# How to reload page in ajax based on comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to reload the page if session is empty but I am unable to do this as the ajax code as below

```
function test()
{
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'view/test/test.php',
        datatype: 'html',
        async:true,
        beforeSend : function(){
            $('#ajax_loader').show(); 
            $('#content').hide();
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data=='cannot')
            { 
                location.reload(true);
            }
            else
            {   
                $('#ajax_loader').hide();    
                $box = $('#content');
                $box.after(data);
                $box.remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
$(document).on('click','#test',$(this),test);
```

and the view test file as

```
<?php include '../../config.php';
if(empty($_SESSION['college_id']))
{
    echo "cannot";
    return;
}
?>
```

The above code is used to check whether session exist or not. If session is empty is simply send `"cannot"`. As the I got the success data as `"cannot"`, I tried to reload the page but the reload function does not work in if condition. Without if condition, it does work. What's wrong?

Comment: if it is working outside if condition, then you need to verify / check the your if condition,

Comment: i checked it by alert

Comment: Try `document.location.reload(true)` instead of `location.reload(true)`.

Comment: @kavita is your alert placed inside if?

Comment: it does not work inside if

Comment: Please tell what response are you getting??

Comment: Be sure to check for whitespace. Trim the data if needed.

Comment: PHP session_start() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can u try this once in you code it may work for you

```
if($.trim(data)=='cannot')
                        {
                            alert("your session has been expired");
                    document.location.reload(true);
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change dataType to **text** and try . Also try to trim the success call back response data before string comparision

Answer (score 0):

Before using the $_SESSION superglobal variables you must start or resume the session by writing

```
session_start()
```

**Note:** This has to be the very first thing (even before the HTML tags)

Comment: Just wrote because it was not mentioned! That is why I asked for the response that was coming :P